# Django variables from templates to views - best practice

Tags: django, view

I realize that using:

```
...
return render_to_response('mytemplate.html',
locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in views is not considered good code and something like:

```
...
return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', {
        'some_variable' : some_variable,
        'some_list': some_list,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

is considered better for its legibility and explicitness. I was just curious how best to deal with variables which may or may not be returned. Should I explicitly set them in the views like this:

```
...
some_variable = None
some_variable = <some business logic>
return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', {
        'some_variable' : some_variable,
        'some_list': some_list,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

which would result in more lengthy view code. Or should I check for existence of the variables before including them in the response?

Of course if I do nothing then I get:

```
local variable 'some_variable' referenced before assignment
```

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: What is supposed to be the problem with your first example?

Comment: @Marcin: it's lazy, sloppy code that often results in context pollution. It *works*, but is considered very un-best practice.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: Lazy and sloppy just mean "I don't like it". Is the problem only context pollution in a view with a lot of locals not used in the template, or is there some further issue?

Comment: No, lazy and sloppy mean lazy and sloppy. "Explicit is better than implicit". If you want development on rails there's another framework that would probably suit you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A middle way is to use the context dictionary itself as a stack.

```
context = {}
if <condition>:
    context['cond1'] = 'foo'

if <condition2>:
    context['cond2'] = 'bar'

return render_to_response('template.html', context)
```

(Also note that since Django 1.3 you can use `render(request, template, context)` instead of the longwinded `context_instance=RequestContext` stuff.)

Comment: of course, if he's using 1.3, it would be better to use class-based views, which renders (no pun intended) both kind of obsolete for the most part. ;)

Comment: Ok, so I tried using `render(request, template, context)`. It seems to work as expected, though now I have a lot of `context['some_variable']` and no dictionary of variables in the `render` call. Is this as clearly legible as the old method?

Answer (score 2):

Either build your context conditionally, i.e.:

```
context = { 'some_list': some_list }

...

if <something>:
    context['some_variable'] = some_variable

...

return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

Or use sensible defaults:

```
return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', {
    'some_variable' : some_variable or 'Default',
    'some_list': some_list,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I like the conciseness of the second method as it doesn't add much to the code length unlike loss of conditional statements. Is there perhaps any disadvantage of this way?

Comment: Actually - this doesn't work for me. I still get the `local variable 'some_variable' referenced before assignment` error if I set `'some_variable': some_variable or None,`